# Is it awkward to say "Good morning" to roommate every day?

Tags: usage, politeness, greetings

I know it is a bit weird to ask this question, yet in the country I am staying, China, people love to say "Good morning" to everyone every morning.

I have never been to other countries except China and I am going to study abroad in America.

Is this social etiquette the same in America and American people say "Good morning" to their roommate every day?

Comment: I'm afraid this question has no answer.  You'll need to pay attention to your roommate and decide for yourself.

Comment: It is awkward in your country to say 'good morning' or some other phrase each day?

Answer (score 5):

> Is this social etiquette the same in America and American people say
>   "Good morning" to their roommate everyday?

It depends. Some people aren't morning people at all. They usually don't care for good mornings because it makes them upset that they are awake and still not sleeping.

However, as long as the roommates aren't totally awkward with each other, I'd say it's OK.

Remember the rule that ***"what words you say generally don't matter, it's HOW you say it, and how it makes people feel that matter"***.

So use a good, polite, energetic *(but not fake enthusiastic)* tone when saying good morning.

Sometimes a person may just be unhappy in general, like having depression, which is very common in America. Do not worry about this though. Still be polite, happy, and real to them and say what you want. Use good tone and manners. In time, they will hopefully be able to become happy again, and be glad it's a new morning.

Answer (score 4):

It's completely okay in any culture, I think. That's because greeting someone in the morning is a gesture of goodwill that the day has begun with some goodness.

Don't we greet our parents with 'Good Morning' daily? Also, I've seen kids greeting this to their parents in many Hollywood movies. That said, it's completely okay to say 'Good Morning' to your roommate everyday.

Comment: I say "Good morning" to my wife and kids every day as well as my coworkers.  It's not always a cheery greeting, but at least a perfunctory "Mornin'" is pretty much expected here in the Midwest US.